# CSS3DObject is not clickable on Firefox

Tags: three.js

I have been experiencing this issue on Firefox latest (haven't tested previous versions).

After I set my CSS3DObject a position:

```
{ "x": 86.72438691726555, "y": 59.24408563389257, "z": -400.84457553626225 }
```

then I cannot click on that object anymore on Firefox (but Chrome works). But when I rotate the camera to other positions then it works.

I have created a fiddle on Codepen to reproduce the issue, Please see in full-screen mode:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tranquyetdev/full/povgBPz)

Can someone tell me when a CSS3DObject can be clickable?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way CSS3DRenderer works is by creating a bunch of `<div>`s and adding transforms to them. The general structure is:

```
<div id="container">
   <div> <!-- This is the renderer.domElement -->
      <div> <!-- This is the scene -->
          <div> <!-- This is the Object3D -->
```

You're experiencing no click events because the Obj3D div gets placed *behind* the Scene div when you give it a negative (`z: -400`) position. I added a border on the scene div of your example so you can better see how it covers it.

The solution was to add the CSS rule `pointer-events: none;` to the scene (via CSS), and `pointer-events: auto;` to the Object3D, that way all hover & click events "pass through" the scene div. You can see it in action here:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var controls;

var Element = function ( id, x, y, z, ry ) {

  var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
  // Add class to assign CSS rules
  div.classList.add("ytVideo");

  var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( div );
  object.position.set( x, y, z );
  object.rotation.y = ry;

  return object;

};

init();
animate();

function init() {

  var container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000 );
  camera.position.set( 500, 350, 750 );

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  
  // Adding class to stage to assign CSS rules
  const sceneDiv = renderer.domElement.childNodes[0];
  sceneDiv.classList.add("scene");

  var position = { "x": 86.72438691726555, "y": 59.24408563389257, "z": -400.84457553626225 }
  var group = new THREE.Group();
  group.add( new Element( 'SJOz3qjfQXU', position.x, position.y, position.z, 0 ) );

  scene.add( group );

  controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  controls.rotateSpeed = 4;

  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  controls.update();
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```css
.scene {
    border: 5px dashed #f90;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.ytVideo {
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    background: #0f0;
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.ytVideo:hover {
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```